# live event not works in ie7?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am displaying checkbox via ajax and i had triggered event when clicking that check box. It wrks in all browser but in ie7 it not works. i clicked on check box nothing happened. my sample code.

```
$("#checkbox_id").live('change',function(){
    alert('check');
});
```

Comment: is it only on ie7 or any ie browser, can you verify ie8 also

Comment: Could it be an error elsewhere in your code? See if this works for you in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/ay2dq/

Comment: it might be someother error in your code , like single quotes or missing commas , ie chokes...in that cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IE7** Wont supports change event in live (i.e `$(#checkbox_id).live('change', function(){})`)

Remember once html code displayed in ajax particularly for checkbox `live change event` wont works in ie7. Use `$('#checkbox_id').live('click',function(){});` for ajax checkbox event triggering.

**My answer might help some one who face same problem**

Comment: Interesting, looks like a bug in jQuery 1.4.2: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/live-method-for-change-event-broken-in-jquery-1-4-2-for-ie-worked-in-1-4-1