# jQuery 1.4.0, live function, change event IE7,8

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.4.0.

I'm trying bind change event to my inputs using live function but it doesn't work on IE7 & 8 (on IE9,10, Firefox it works).

```
$("input:text").live("change", function(e) {
    alert("works!");
});
```

Regards.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476634/live-event-not-works-in-ie7 - I imagine you're being forced to use 1.4 for some reason but if not then I'd really recommend using a more up to date version and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9903328/2287470

Comment: **Note that:** In old(6,7,8) IE `change` event fire only then element lose the user focus. But there is a [`propertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx) event, but it deprecated since IE9.

Comment: @Joe Ye, I have to use 1.4.0. This problem doesnt exist in 1.4.3 (maybe even in 1.4.2) so is it possible to fix this in 1.4.0 with additional code?

Comment: first we have to figure out what bugfix fixed the issue, then we might be able to create a patch that would solve it in 1.4.0

Comment: When the bug tracker comes back online, i'm guessing this one will be the cause: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5851

Comment: Thank you for link @KevinB. I think will be hard to create this patch because live function in jQuery 1.4.2 is completely rewritten (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.js , http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js)

Comment: I found fix! https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/435772e29b4ac4ccfdefbc4045d43f714e153381 Is it possible to fix this with additional code instead of making changes in jQuery library?

Comment: Yes, it's very easy to apply the fix. i'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update the focusout filter for the change event to match what it was updated to in 1.4.1 which fixed the issue. You can include this anywhere in your code, as long as it comes before the user changes the input and after the jquery core is included.

```
function testChange(e) {
    var elem = e.target,
        data, val;

    if (!formElems.test(elem.nodeName) || elem.readOnly) {
        return;
    }

    data = jQuery.data(elem, "_change_data");
    val = getVal(elem);

    if (val === data) {
        return;
    }

    // the current data will be also retrieved by beforeactivate
    if (e.type !== "focusout" || elem.type !== "radio") {
        jQuery.data(elem, "_change_data", val);
    }

    if (data != null || val) {
        e.type = "change";
        return jQuery.event.trigger(e, arguments[1], elem);
    }
}

jQuery.event.special.change.filters.focusout = testChange;
```

Commit: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/435772e29b4ac4ccfdefbc4045d43f714e153381

Comment: It doesn't work because testChange function requires formElems variable and getVal function. Of course I can copy this from jQuery library but is it better way?

Comment: No, there is no better way that doesn't involve instead upgrading jquery.